# What are the ARIA attributes supported by JAWS 11

Tags: html, screen-readers, wai-aria

I would like to know which ARIA attributes are supported by JAWS, as the users I am targeting will be using the JAWS screen reader.

So far I’ve failed to find technical documentation targeted at developers provided by Freedom Scientific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No documentation for JAWS 11 that I can find, but the [JAWS 12 documentation page](http://www.freedomscientific.com/documentation/screen-readers.asp) has a link to a [JAWS Support for ARIA Word document](http://www.freedomscientific.com/PDF/visionloss/manuals/DevDoc/JAWS-ARIA-Support.doc).